# To Prepare Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, dos

Please help to prepare batch script on DOS.

This script should run in following manner :

1. Telent the IP and use the existing passwd (explicitly given in the script).
2. After the telnet, it shows MENU options
3. MB station
4. RC
5. ODU
6. AP
7. SU
8. Exit

> type 1 // a  "MB station" MENU options will open i.e.
>   
>   1 - Show
>   2 - Unit Control
>
> type 2 // UC MENU options will open i.e

1 - Change Password
2 - Reset

> type 1 //change passwd MENU options will open i.e.

1 - Change PC Password
2 - Change LU Password
3 - Change Admin Password

> type 3 // to change ADMIN passwd

MB station - Change Admin Password
Enter New Password                  : XYZ enter
Re-enter Password                   : XYZ enter

New password accepted

3 times escape // to escape from telnet

1.MB station
2. RC
3. ODU
4. AP
5. SU
6. Exit

> type 6        // to exit
>   Exit? [Y/N] y

Connection to host lost.

then move to step with different IP. The IP values will be given by the user one-time while executing the script at the prompt e.g. ./pass-change IPs.txt

Comment: Stackover flow is a site to help answer programming questions, not to get other people to write code for you.  Start writing your script and come back with a specific problem you run into while writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with this :

```
@ECHO OFF

:BEGIN
CLS
ECHO.                 
ECHO          Oleg Grishko  + Flora  = Love          
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO        1=Remove All Hard Drive Partitions
ECHO        2=FDISK Hard Drive
ECHO        3=Format Hard Drive
ECHO        4=Dell Utilities
ECHO        5=Re-image
ECHO        6=Exit To DOS
ECHO.
ECHO       To bring this menu back type GO.BAT at the dos prompt.
ECHO.
CHOICE /N /C:123456 

ECHO.
If ERRORLEVEL ==6 GOTO SIX
If ERRORLEVEL ==5 GOTO FIVE
If ERRORLEVEL ==4 GOTO FOUR
IF ERRORLEVEL ==3 GOTO THREE
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO TWO
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO ONE
GOTO END

:SIX
EXIT
GOTO QUIT

:FIVE
call re-image.bat
GOTO END

:FOUR
call dell.bat
GOTO END

:THREE
cd dos
call format.bat
GOTO END

:TWO
cd dos
call fdisk.bat
GOTO END

:ONE
cd dos
call blast.bat
GOTO END

:END
cd\
REM ECHO Completed. Bringing up DOS menu again...
REM pause
REM f:go.bat

:QUIT
f:
```